# elasticsearch not started on macOS

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, macos-catalina

When I try to start elasticsearch on my macOS laptop, it does not appear to have started.  So much of the answers I find on the internet do not relate to using `brew` on macOS.

See this command line history of trying to start it.

```
:>brew services stop elasticsearch 
Stopping `elasticsearch`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `elasticsearch` (label: homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch)
:>brew services start elasticsearch
==> Successfully started `elasticsearch` (label: homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch)
:>curl http://localhost:9200      
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
:>curl https://localhost:9200      
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
:>lsof -i :9200     
:>sudo ps -ef | grep elastic
  501 85360 68989   0  9:51AM ttys000    0:00.00 grep elastic
```

Also using the Network Utility I see nothing is listening at the port 9200.

[image]

I am using Catalina Version 10.15.7 (19H1030).

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

My elasticsearch version is

```
Version: 6.0.1, Build: 601be4a/2017-12-04T09:29:09.525Z, JVM: 1.8.0_121
```

The location of the binary on my `PATH` is `/usr/local/bin/elasticsearch`

EDIT:

There was a comment to include any error messages or the output.  If this was not clear, what I wrote is the only output.  The only output to stdout or stderr from `brew services start elasticsearch` is "Successfully started elasticsearch".

However, when trying `elasticsearch -d` from the command line I get this:

```
:>elasticsearch
2021-05-24 09:33:08,875 main ERROR Could not register mbeans java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission" "register")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:585)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.checkMBeanTrustPermission(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1848)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:322)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.register(Server.java:389)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:167)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:140)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:556)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:261)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:206)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:220)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:197)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configureStatusLogger(LogConfigurator.java:172)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:141)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:120)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:290)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:130)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:121)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:85)

ERROR: no log4j2.properties found; tried [/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch] and its subdirectories
```

The `/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch` directory exists but is empty.

```
:>ls -l /usr/local/etc
...
drwxr-xr-x   2 marlpier  admin     64 May 19 16:30 elasticsearch
...
:>find /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch 
/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch
```

Maybe my `jvm.options` file is not found.  Where should it be?

Comment: Hi there, I think  that we are missing some info here. It seems so, as the service won't really start. Can you provide us the error messages or the output of elasticsearch? I think that you can also simply start elasticsearch on the console to check if there are some errors, e.g., by executing  `/usr/local/bin/elasticsearch` without brew. 
Kind regards,
Mirko

Comment: This is an excellent response and what I am looking for.  I need help finding where there is missing information.

The answer to error messages or the output of elasticsearch is no more than I wrote in my question.  The only output to stdout or stderr from `brew services start elasticsearch` is "Successfully started elasticsearch".  If someone can tell me of an error log file that would be what I hope will solve my problem and get me unstuck.

Comment: Hi Marlin, what I meant, is that you can also start elasticsearch in the foreground without using brew. In this way you could see why it is not starting. However, if you are not confident with it, we can use brew. The log file should be located `/usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch` as reported in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/brew.html).

Kind regards,
Mirko

Comment: I'm sorry, I did it both with and without `-d` but should have documented it without.  The most recent file in `/usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch` is from December 7.  So no new log entries when I use `brew services start elasticsearch`.

Comment: That is quite strange, can you share the configuration file, in particular any line related to logging? Perhaps inadvertedly you changed the logs location. Can you please check if the user who runs elasticsearch has the right permissions to access the directories listed in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/brew.html). Sadly, I never used an apple device nor brew myself, so I cannot tell nor guess where to look. It can also be, that logs are not written, because elasticsearch fails before initialising logs.

Comment: Strange indeed especially from the message in the output "Successfully started".  if it dies before logging works, then it should have not gotten far enough to reports successfully starting.  That success message should be after the logging succeeds or fails.  Also stopping it through brew reports it is stopping but stopping it a second time says it is not running.

The documentation says the conf is in the `/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch` directory but that directory is empty.  Where should configuration be for me to look for?

Comment: I don't care if we use brew or the `elasticsearch` command.  I have had problems finding advice because much of what is on the internet refers to UNIX commands for Ubantu which are not available on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was that `brew reinstall elasticsearch` was not working.

Doing `brew uninstall elasticsearch` gave a java error.  So to uninstall java, `brew uninstall java` also gave a java error.

Answer to uninstall java was [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/90904) by removing the java directory.

After that I was able to uninstall `elasticsearch` and then install it again with `brew`.  Now it works.